# Adding event listeners to multiple input elements using plain JS (not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, validation, input, dom-events, this

I have a code block that works perfectly in jQuery but it's the last bit of a project I am converting to plain vanilla Javascript with the specific aim to remove any and all dependencies on jQuery.

Here is the existing code block at issue:

```
$("input[data-pattern='comma']").on({
    keyup: function() {inputComma($(this));}
});
```

How do I achieve this same functionality using ONLY plain pure JS?

**Note:** inputComma is a custom handler that conforms the value for EACH input element instance to a comma-delimited regex pattern as the user is typing.

If it helps, I tried...

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[data-pattern='comma']").forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("keyup", function() {inputComma(elem);});
});
```

and also...

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[data-pattern='comma']").forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("keyup", () => {inputComma(elem);});
});
```

I know jQuery's $(this) is different from "this" and that arrow functions also materially affect which "this" is being referenced. I tried to get around that issue by referencing the iterating object but I think that may be part of my problem. Not opposed to using the "this" pointer if there is a way to make it work in pure JS.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Your code looks reasonable, what problems are you having with it?

Comment: Assuming you also changed `inputComma` to accept a plain DOM element instead of a jQuery wrapper, this should work.

Comment: The jQuery version works solidly but I'm specifically trying to do this in pure Javascript (no jQuery). My attempts so far don't throw any console errors but it appears my handler is not even getting called in the plain JS version.

Comment: @Bergi I made no changes to `inputComma`. It is just taking whatever the event listener feeds it: `function inputComma(input) {...}`

Comment: "*it appears my handler is not even getting called*" - how did you test this? Also did you verify that `querySelectorAll` returns the elements that you expect?

Comment: @Bergi A simple temporary `console.log` in `inputComma` just to see if the handler was called and it wasn't. I have not yet tested what the query selector returns specifically. Candidly, I just assumed my syntax on the pure JS event listener was wrong. I guess I could assign the query selector to a variable and `console.log` what, if anything, it targeted.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you again so much for your help. I've since discovered that my handler IS being raised AND it is targeting the right elements. The problem is something else I overlooked which was the use of the .val() method inside my handler. A lingering remnant of jQuery in my code that was making my whole handler return false because it believed my input field was empty. Once I rework that part of my handler, everything should work. I should've done more debugging before I jumped on here but I was so unsure of my syntax on the event listener, I was all but certain the problem was there.

Comment: Everything works now @Bergi. I can't thank you enough. Cheers!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think this can be better done using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation). It would look something like:

```
document.addEventListener(`keyup`, handle);

function handle(evt) {
  if (evt.target.dataset?.pattern === `comma`) {
    return inputComma(evt.target);
  }
}

function inputComma(elem) {...}
```

Comment: @Kooilnc Event delegation was a great suggestion here since I actually have additional input pattern also associated with keyup events AND your syntax helped me expose the real issue that was hanging up my code and that was a lingering bit of jQuery in my handler that used the jQuery .val() method instead of the .value property that caused my handler to return false and silently exit out. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Hi @inworlder, glad it helped you a bit ;)

Comment: Hi KooiInc! You helped a LOT! Without you and @Bergi, I'm sure I'd still be lost in space. Solution achieved. I can't thank you enough. Cheers!